# From 'start with' and 'connect by' in Oracle to Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursive-query

UPD:

I want to convert this Oracle code:

```
select lpad(c4, length(c4) + (level*2)-2 , ' '), lpad(c2, length(c2) + (level*2)-2 , ' ')
from (select root_id c1, root_tab_col_name c2, null c3, 'root_table' c4 from root_table
    union all
    select second_tab_id, second_tab_col_name, root_tab_id, 'second_table' from second_table
    union all
    select third_tab_id, third_tab_col_name, second_tab_id, 'third_table' from third_table)
start with c3 is null
connect by prior c1 = c3;
```

to PostgreSQL form. Could someone help me? With regards.

UPD:

I have 3 tables connected with foreign keys:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Result of this query:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some test data and the expected result? That would make things easier for the PostgreSQL experts that don't know about Oracle to provide an answer.

Comment: I see no attempt of yours to solve this problem. That makes the question off-topic, since this is no code writing service. If you search related questions or read the PostgreSQL documentation, you can easily find how to use `WITH RECURSIVE` in PostgresSQL to solve the problem.

Comment: I found this solution in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49537740/migrate-query-with-start-with-and-connect-by-prior-from-oracle-to-postgresql . But instead of the table name after `from`, I have query: ```select root_id c1, root_tab_col_name c2, null c3, 'root_table' c4 from root_table
    union all
    select second_tab_id, second_tab_col_name, root_tab_id, 'second_table' from second_table
    union all
    select third_tab_id, third_tab_col_name, second_tab_id, 'third_table' from third_table```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
with request_base as (
       select root_id c1, root_tab_col_name c2, null c3, 'root_table' c4 from root_table
    union all
       select second_tab_id, second_tab_col_name, root_tab_id, 'second_table' from second_table
     union all
    select third_tab_id, third_tab_col_name, second_tab_id, 'third_table' from third_table
)
,req2 as (WITH recursive recurs1(tables_name,texts,n) as (
      select c4,c2,c1 rel from request_base where c3 is null
    UNION 
        select c4,c2,c1 from request_base,recurs1 where c3=n
 )
    select tables_name,texts from recurs1
)
select * from req2
```