# Migration fron Oracle DB to Postgesql Hierarchical Queries

Tags: postgresql, oracle, database-migration, recursive-query

I'm doing of migrate of Oracle DB to PosgreSQL. I have such a Hierarchical query, like below. I did easier hierarchical queries with success. But I can't do this query. Can Anybody help to make a queries for PostgreSQL?

Oracle query:

```sql
select count(*) cnt
from   list nl,
       parts spl
where  nl.month     = Month_
and    nl.year      = Year_
and    nl.date_del  is null
and    nl.id(+)     = spl.id
and    nl.dep_owner = dep_owner_
and    nl.dep_id in ( select d.dep_id
                      from departments d
                      connect bt prior d.dep_id = d.parent_id
                      start with d.dep_id = dep_id_)
connect by prior spl.id = spl.parent_id
start with spl.index = trim(part_index_)
```

Postgres query:

```
 WITH RECURSIVE cteroot AS (SELECT count(*) AS cnt
                       FROM parts spl
                       LEFT JOIN list nl ON spl."ID" = nl."ID"
                       where nl."MONTH"= Month_
                       and nl."YEAR" = Year_
                       and nl."DATE_DEL" is null
                       and nl."DEP_OWNER" = dep_owner_
                       and nl."DEP_ID" IN (WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (SELECT "DEP_ID"
                                           FROM departments
                                           where "DEP_ID"= dep_id_
                                           UNION
                                           SELECT d."DEP_ID"
                                           FROM departments d
                                           JOIN cte ON d."PARENT_ID"= cte."DEP_ID")
                                           SELECT "DEP_ID"
                                           FROM cte
                                           )
                       and spl."INDEX" = TRIM(part_index_)
                       UNION
                       SELECT count(*) AS cntd
                       FROM parts spld
                       LEFT JOIN list nld ON spl."ID" = nld."ID"
                       where nld."MONTH"= Month_
                       and nld."YEAR" = Year_
                       and nld."DATE_DEL" is null
                       and nld."DEP_OWNER" = dep_owner_
                       and nld."DEP_ID" IN (WITH RECURSIVE cted AS (SELECT "DEP_ID"
                                                                    FROM departments dt
                                                   where dt."DEP_ID"= dep_id_
                                                   UNION
                                                   SELECT td."DEP_ID"
                                                   FROM departments td
                                                   JOIN cted ON td."PARENT_ID"= cted."DEP_ID")
                                             SELECT "DEP_ID"
                                             FROM cted
                                             )
 SELECT count(*) cntv
 FROM cteroot)`
```

This code works but no correct

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49537740/migrate-query-with-start-with-and-connect-by-prior-from-oracle-to-postgresql

Comment: Thanks, but no. This case from your link is easier. My case is more confusing.

Comment: Slight misconception. Due to the order the tables are specified (`list`, `parts`) the predicate `nl.id(+) = spl.id`  translates to *RIGHT OUTER JOIN*. The + operator is specified on the deficient side (ie null if none exists). See [Left and Right Joins Using the Plus (+) Sign in Oracle](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/left-and-right-joins-using-the-plus-sign-in-oracle/#performing-outer-joins-using-the-symbol).

Comment: @Belayer You would be correct about the direction but, as I mention in my answer, it is not an `OUTER` join as the `CONNECT BY` clause requires non-`NULL` values and forces the query to be evaluated as an `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` in the Oracle query. Yes, you may use `(+)` in the join but in the `START WITH` and `CONNECT BY` clauses you require `spl.index` and `spl.id` to equal another value and that will never be true when an `OUTER JOIN` has occurred and the values would be `NULL` so the join can only be an `INNER JOIN`.

Therefore, your Oracle query is effectively:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) cnt
FROM   list l
       INNER JOIN parts p
       ON ( l.id = p.id )
WHERE  l.month     = Month_
AND    l.year      = Year_
AND    l.date_del  IS NULL
AND    l.dep_owner = dep_owner_
AND    l.dep_id IN ( SELECT d.dep_id
                     FROM   departments d
                     CONNECT BY PRIOR d.dep_id = d.parent_id
                     START WITH d.dep_id = dep_id_ )
CONNECT BY PRIOR p.id = p.parent_id
START WITH p.index = trim(part_index_)
```

At the least, you need to change your `LEFT JOIN`s to `INNER JOIN`s.

You also do not join the main recursive sub-query factoring clause (CTE) to itself to make it recursive.

You want something like (untested as you have not shared any sample data):

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE depts AS (
  SELECT "DEP_ID"
  FROM   departments
  WHERE  "DEP_ID"= dep_id_
UNION ALL
  SELECT d."DEP_ID"
  FROM   departments d
         INNER JOIN depts p ON d."PARENT_ID" = p."DEP_ID"
),
recursive_parts AS (
  SELECT p."ID" 
  FROM   list l
         INNER JOIN parts p
         ON p."ID" = l."ID"
  WHERE  l."MONTH"     = Month_
  AND    l."YEAR"      = Year_
  AND    l."DATE_DEL"  IS NULL
  AND    l."DEP_OWNER" = dep_owner_
  AND    l."DEP_ID"    IN ( SELECT "DEP_ID" FROM depts )
  AND    p."INDEX" = TRIM(part_index_)
UNION ALL
  SELECT p."ID"
  FROM   list l
         INNER JOIN parts p
         ON p."ID" = l."ID"
         INNER JOIN recursive_parts r
         ON r."ID" = p."PARENT_ID"
  WHERE  l."MONTH"     = Month_
  AND    l."YEAR"      = Year_
  AND    l."DATE_DEL"  IS NULL
  AND    l."DEP_OWNER" = dep_owner_
  AND    l."DEP_ID"    IN ( SELECT "DEP_ID" FROM depts )
)
SELECT count(*) cntv
FROM   recursive_parts
```

Comment: Hello thanks. In my case i can't change the Oracle query, its not mine. I can change and create Postgresql query. Can you share with me PostgeSQL code that converted from no altered Oracle code.

Comment: @AlexGro The whole point is that regardless of if you rewrite the Oracle code or not, the Oracle code will behave like the rewritten code because the filter conditions force the join to be an `INNER JOIN`. You do not need to rewrite the Oracle code you just need to know that your assumptions about how it should behave are probably wrong. As for the PostgreSQL code, it is at the bottom of the answer and is based on how the Oracle code will actually behave and not on your assumptions of what it probably should do. As mentioned in the answer, it is untested as you have not supplied a [MRE].

Comment: Many thanks, this runnig like clockwork.